# View not displayed "Sometimes" Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

In my AppDelegate->applicationWillFinishLaunching i load two view controller with

```
NSViewController *v = [[MyCustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"aNib" bundle:nil];
```

MyCustomViewController's initWithNibName:bundle: method is an auto-generated:

```
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
...
```

I add their view in a Custom View: *[theMainView addSubview:[v view]]*

I can't understand why sometimes (like one out of ten times) the views are loaded but not displayed.

EDIT:

```
MyCustomViewController1 *v = [[MyCustomViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"aNib" bundle:nil];
[themainview addSubview:[v view]];

MyCustomViewController2 *v2 = [[MyCustomViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"aNib2" bundle:nil];
[themainview addSubview:[v2 view]];

self.view1 = [[themainview subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
self.view2  = [[themainview subviews] objectAtIndex:1];

[view2 setHidden:YES];
```

view1 and view2 are 2 NSView properties synthesized in the AppDelegate

Comment: Does your application use garbage collection? If so, are you keeping strong references to the view controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue could  be your relying on the views being at specific indexes of the themainview's `subviews` array. You need to be certain you're setting the correct views.

Try this instead:

```
MyCustomViewController1 *v = [[MyCustomViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"aNib" bundle:nil];
[themainview addSubview:[v view]];

MyCustomViewController2 *v2 = [[MyCustomViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"aNib2" bundle:nil];
[themainview addSubview:[v2 view]];

self.view1 = [v view];
self.view2  = [v2 view];

[view2 setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the problem is still there